# How to migrate from AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter to RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, wicket

I'm building REST services via *Spring MVC* in the application where the GUI is managed by *Wicket*. Basically, all I need is the `DispatcherServlet` and a controller with `@RequestMapping`/`@RequestBody`.

Because services serve JSON, I need to set `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. I can do this via `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and that works fine:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("cz.swsamuraj.wicketspring")
public class SpringRestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter() {
        HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters = { new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()};

        AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setMessageConverters(converters);

        return  adapter;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is deprecated and it's recommended to use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instead.

But if I use this configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("cz.swsamuraj.wicketspring")
public class SpringRestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestHandler() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

I receive an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [cz.swsamuraj.wicketspring.ws.api.QuestionApiController@69f8a79f]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
```

So, my question is: **how can I set up a handler adapter in the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`?**

I spent couple of days of research, but I didn't find any useful example of how to configure `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. All the advices just says to put `@EnableWebMvc` on the configuration, but this is not the way because of this Wicket-Spring coexistence.

---

Just to provide a full context, I've created a small buildable and runnable project on Bitbucket: [sw-samuraj/blog-wicket-spring-rest](https://bitbucket.org/sw-samuraj/blog-wicket-spring-rest)

Comment: check this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5004

Comment: As far as I understand, you need a single Spring context, several URLs for REST services and the rest of URLs is mapped by wicket. Your issue is how to create a single context and map both of those technologies on URLs sharing this context, is that correct?

Comment: Almost correct. First, it's not necessary to have just one *Spring* context - currently, I have two (one for *Wicket*, one for REST). Second, *Wicket* shouldn't be aware of those REST URLs (and eventually of REST context). But this is already working for me. The only issue is the one in the title (migrate `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`).

Comment: I added a link to a sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with different approach - with usage of `WebApplicationInitializer`, I was able to put the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation on my configuration class and therefore neither the bean `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, nor `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` are necessary. JSON now works fine, out-of-the-box.

**Configuration**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("cz.swsamuraj.wicketspring")
public class SpringRestConfiguration {
    // some additional beans needed for business logic
}
```

**WebApplicationInitializer**

```java
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(SpringRestConfiguration.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/rest/*");
    }
}
```

**Example project**

Complete working example is on *Bitbucket*: [blog-wicket-spring-rest](https://bitbucket.org/sw-samuraj/blog-wicket-spring-rest)